# how to render page phantom js every minute

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to render a website page with phantom js, argar can render automatically every few minutes?

Here is my code:

```
var url = 'http://live.7msport.com';
var page = require ('webpage'). create ();
var fs = require ('fs');

page.open (url, function (status) {
    if (status! == 'success') {
        console.log ('Fail');
        phantom.exit ();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout (function () {
       fs.write ('index.php', page.content, 'w');
       phantom.exit ();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:->

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for the clearInterval() method.

1000 ms = 1 second.

Tip: To execute a function only once, after a specified number of milliseconds, use the setTimeout() method.

```js
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>
<p>After clicking away the alert box, an new alert box will appear in 3 seconds. This goes on forever...</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var url = 'http://live.7msport.com'; 
var page = require ('webpage'). create (); 
var fs = require ('fs'); 
page.open (url, function (status) { if (status! == 'success') { console.log ('Fail'); phantom.exit (); } 
else 
{ window.setInterval (function () {
fs.write ('index.php', page.content, 'w');
phantom.exit (); 
}, 60000); }

});
```

setInterval takes 2 arguments 
1.)Function
2.)interval to again render the page(in milliseconds)

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  Including a brief description of *how* the code answers the question will help others with the same problem.

Comment: @exsanrenaldhi now  check the above example.